# Selenium clicking button function

Tags: c#, mysql, selenium

```
 /// <summary>
    /// clicks on an element given the elements ID and a waiting timeout
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="driver"></param>
    /// <param name="ID"></param>
    /// <param name="timeout"></param>
    public static void clickElement(IWebDriver driver, String ID, int timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id(ID)));
            driver.FindElement(By.Id(ID)).Click();
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("On Selenium Action click " + ID + " after 10 seconds, this button didn't appear on the page", "Use Case 1 Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            throw;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("After waiting for 10 seconds, the page was not loaded !", "Use case Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to get this function makes the difference between the two type of exceptions i wanna catch which are Page was not loaded or button was not there ( ID has been changed or the button has been removed ).

Answer (score 1):

The TimeoutException can indicate that the click action did not return appropriately - this is considered a Driver Timeout. Eg: You click on the submit button, the server is processing the request for 5 minutes, but the drivers timeout is 60 seconds - so it times out.

You appear to be working to the convention of using Static methods, most likely within a Function Library.
I would discourage this approach - as it is anti-pattern to object oriented.

In our own test framework, we have specialized types that encapsulate the IWebElement class/interface that Selenium provides and we put our own functionality on top of that.

So instead of calling

```
IWebElement textbox = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
textbox.TypeKeys("Administrator");
```

We call

```
Textbox mytextbox = new Textbox(By.Id("username"));
mytextbox.SetText("Administrator");
```

The constructor for the Textbox class will perform the existence checks (or non-existence checks) if required.

Furthermore - we have another specialized interface/class called 'IPage / Page'
Which implements IDisposable, so we can utilize Page Object model within the context of a Using() statement.

Eg:

```
using(LoginPage page = new LoginPage())
{
      page.UsernameTextBox().SetText("Administrator");
      page.PasswordTextBox().SetText("Password12121212");
      page.SubmitButton().Click();
}
```

By using IDisposable in combination with your Page Model approach, you can make it so that the constructor for the LoginPage class - knows to synchronize on a specific object on the login page itself.
Eg: 
When the LoginPage class is instantiated, we check for the existence of the UsernameTextBox - if it does not exist, then the page has not loaded properly, therefore, there is no point in executing the contents of the using statement.

I generally recommend having the synchronization object set to the last object expected to load on screen per page.
This way you can get your code to intelligently wait for the page to load before proceeding into the inner context of the using statement.

Using this approach, you could detect whether your page failed to load, or if the object failed to load.
Lets not forget, the page could load, but still be the wrong page through data or code issue with the application under test.
This is a scenario that the TimeoutException would not catch.

The typical structure we follow in our framework is - just in case you want to model something similar.

BaseElement - Which has the IWebElement as a private field - all work is done on the IWebElement.
BaseElement will have most of the functionality defined and implemented at this level as protected or public methods where appropriate.

We then extend / inherit from the BaseElement when defining our other specialized classes.
Eg: ButtonLink, Textbox, DropdownSelects, RadioCheckboxes etc

We override methods where appropriate or simply redirect the calls to the base method within the BaseElement.

Our reasoning for designing our framework this way was based on the logic of 'Not every webelement is a textbox, so why would you treat it as such?'
This being the case- We only get the intellisense / options for a drop down, if the object in question actually is a drop down.

In .Net coding / programming - strongly typing your classes is generally an encouraged principle - so treating everything like every other type of class - even if Selenium or the wider QA community allows / encourages it, is not necessarily a good idea. 
Building a framework on top of the base Selenium types will allow you to handle bespoke occasions where you need to click on buttons using Javascript or you need to get data out of Highchart graphs etc

Sorry for the rant - I just thought this might be food for thought and an alternative approach to your problem.

Comment: Hi, Do you have a sample of this framework out on github somewhere? I'm interested to take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot share it - it is proprietary to the company that I work for. I can however share some of the principles around how it was developed. Which is what I have tried to do above.

Essentially - our specialized types - which include ButtonLinks, Highcharts, BootstrapDropdowns etc are just wrapped classes which hold a reference to the IWebElement - and then we override the default functionality with out own implementation to make it work better than Selenium out of the box. I might try to write a blog entry around it to show how we constructed the framework.

Comment: A blog entry would be great. Please ping me when you complete it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi JeffC - https://ninjaqa.net/post/2018/04/11/selenium-automation-strongly-typed-classes
I only started the blog - but I am addressing some subjects and 'rant' like topics. The last entry I just finished addresses what I refer to above in regards to making Selenium more object oriented in how we use it for testing.

Comment: Thanks. One suggestion... in your `Click()` method you could wait for a few seconds and poll the click until you no longer get the `InvalidOperationException`. In my experience, most of the time this exception occurs is when there is a "Loading..." popup or the like. If that happens, it will likely go away in a few seconds and you will get more "human-like" clicks before resorting to JS clicks. The downside is that you may wait a few seconds and still end up with a JS click. I guess it depends on whether the occasional few seconds lost is worth avoiding the JS clicks.

Comment: Entirely true - I guess what I am trying to emphasize is that by using wrapper classes, it gives the automation engineer the ability to make those choices and decisions and implement them easier, than using just the out of the box selenium functionality. In some cases we use Javascript a little too much, but in some cases there are just some weird page designs that just necessitate it. Also - the VerifyText example I touch on in the article is particularly useful, because objects such as textbox inputs and text areas need to be handled slightly differently.